# Query in Ecto embeds_many association

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto, jsonb

Trying to experiment with Ecto `embeds_many`, and work great, until I need to query on some data in the embedded field.

So I have something like a `product` that `embeds_many` `categories`

```
schema "products" do
  field :code, :string, null: false

  embeds_many :categories, Category,
    on_replace: :delete,
    primary_key: {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: false}
  do
    field :name, :string
  end
end

def create_changeset(%Product{} = product, attrs) do
  product
  |> cast(attrs, [:code])
  |> cast_embed(:categories, with: &attributes_changeset/2)
end

def attributes_changeset(%{} = product_attribute, attrs) do
  product_attribute
  |> cast(attrs, [:id, :name])
end
```

After creating products I end up with something like this in the postgres table

id   code   categories

```
1    11     {"{\"id\": \"dress\", \"name\": \"Dress\"},
             "{\"id\": \"shirt\", \"name\": \"Shirt\"}}
2    22     {"{\"id\": \"dress\", \"name\": \"Dress\"}}
```

So now I want to query all `products` where `id == "dress"`, and of course I would like to get the 2 results above.

I have experimented with something like this:
`q = from p in Product, where: fragment("? @> ?", p.categories, '{"id": "dress"}')` but transforms the array in integers: `operator does not exist: jsonb[] @> integer[]` ... `WHERE (p0."categories" @> ARRAY[123,34,105,100,34,58,32,34,100,114,101,115,115,34,125])`

or that:
`q = from p in Product, where: fragment("? @> ?", p.categories, "[{\"id\": \"dress\"}]")`, getting `malformed array literal: "[{"id": "dress"}]"`

What I hoped was something like:
`q = from p in Product, where: fragment("? -> 'id' = ?", p.categories, "rochie")` but not sure at all if that will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `categories` is a `jsonb[]` here, not a plain `json`, the operator `@>` won't work with it directly. You can use `ANY` and `<@` to do what you want:

```
where: fragment("? <@ ANY(?)", ~s|{"id": "dress"}|, p.categories)
```

This will run `'{"id": "dress"}' <@ ?` for each category in the categories array and return true if any of them match.

(`~s|"a"|` is just a cleaner way of writing `"\"a\""`.)

Comment: Thanks so much! it works perfectly. If I may ask you one more question, what would be the way to look for something like `id in ["dress", "shirt"]`

Basically to check for many categories.

Comment: I can't think of any solution for an arbitrary number of cases.. ANY is only allowed on the RHS. For a fixed number of cases, you can just `OR` the same predicate, e.g. `fragment("? <@ ANY(?)", ~s|{"id": "dress"}|, p.categories)
or
fragment("? <@ ANY(?)", ~s|{"id": "shirt"}|, p.categories)`.

Comment: yes, the `or` looks like a good solution. Thanks so much again for your help.